# Why do I get an error dialog with "You must rename an identifier" from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am continuously getting this error message: "You must rename an identifier" from Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

The error dialog is:

- Title: Microsoft Visual Studio,
- Icon: Red circle with a white X (Error),
- Body: "You must rename an identifier."
- Available Buttons: OK

[image: Error Message]

I have already ran a repair of my Visual Studio installation, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: Simple cross check, just to get sure: You tested this with a new (empty) solution and it appears also?

Comment: When does this error dialog appear? Do you have to click a button or launch a build, for example?

Comment: Whenever i start write codes it start to show this message. thanx for your interest.

Comment: Remove any heavy weights off the F2 function key.  Try another keyboard.

Comment: Have you applied the latest Visual Studio update available under "Tools" - "Extensions and Updates..."?

Comment: I cant understand. My F2 function key is used for boot loading of my laptop. otherwise i didnt assign my job for F2 key. pls elaborate ur answer.

Comment: For those looking to hunt down the source of this message, it is defined in Roslyn [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/73a50745e0b4d0aa617eae9c50159b3d9b5d1f59/src/EditorFeatures/Core/EditorFeaturesResources.resx#L390-L392) as  `EditorFeaturesResources.You_must_rename_an_identifier`, which is used 5 places, all related to renaming.

Comment: I downloaded my VS2017 only 2 weeks ago. But now i can see there is 2 updates: 'Product Update' and 'Visual studio marketplace'. I havent updated them.

Comment: Under "Product Updates", if you see a "Visual Studio Update ...", then install it and see if your problem goes away.  If so, someone fixed it, but I didn't find anything about this particular problem in the release notes.

Comment: Yes there is a "Visual Studio Update". i am now updating it.

Comment: No. the problem isnt solved. i just updated. but the message comes continuously. Hey Matt any other suggestion please.

Comment: * I went to menu menu, Tools, Options, Environment, Keyboard, then pressed the Reset button from a suggestion of 'Viorel_
(MCC, MVP)' of msdn. After this the message isnt coming. but i will monitor for few hour to be sure the problem is solved.

Comment: That makes sense, as you may have had some common key mapped as a shortcut for a rename somehow... If that works, be sure to add an answer of your own so you can get points and help the next person who comes along with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to menu==> Tools==> Options==> Environment==> Keyboard, then pressed the Reset button. After this the message isn't coming. i think there had some common key mapped as a shortcut as Matt Johnson said. Resetting buttons clears common key mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error and resolved it by restarting visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

According to issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39684) Renaming(refactoring) are causing this error. Closing and only opening relevant code editor/window(not whole Visual Studio App) resolved the issue. Make sure you don't put more than one caret not to get this weird error.

Note: I tried this on Visual Studio 2022 17.7.4

Answer (score 0):

I just highlight the word i want to rename and cut it, then write the new word and save. that fixed the problem for me